# How many leaves are there before a subtree?

Tags: python, tree, nltk

I'm using [nltk trees](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree) to read stanford syntactic parses of text (using `Tree.fromstring()`), and I'm after a way of finding the *leaf* position of a given subtree in the bigger tree. Basically, I'd like the opposite of [`leaf_treeposition()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.leaf_treeposition).

In the tree `t`, I got the subtree `np`, **what I want is the index `x`** so that :

```
t.leaves()[x] == np.leaves()[0] # x = ???(t, np)
```

---

I wouldn't want to use `t.leaves().index(...)` because maybe there are several occurences of `np` in the sentence and I need the correct one rather than the first one.

**What I have** is the *tree* position of `np` within `t` (being a `ParentedTree`), `np.treeposition()`, such that :

```
t[np.treeposition()] == np
```

I guess a tedious solution would be to sum leaves for all left_siblings of `np` at all levels. Or I could go through all leaves until `leaf_treeposition(leaf)` equals `np.treeposition()+"[0]"*`, but that sounds suboptimal.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** There is a straightforward solution after all:

1. Construct the tree position of the first leaf of your subtree.
2. Look it up in the list of all leaf treepositions.

Setup:

```
>>> t = ParentedTree.fromstring('(S (NP (D the) (N dog)) (VP (V chased) (NP (D the) (N cat))))')
>>> np_pos = (1,1)
>>> np = t[np_pos]
>>> print(np)
(NP (D the) (N cat))
```

For step 1, I concatenate the tree position of `np` with the tree 
position of the first leaf *within* `np`. The list of all leaf treepositions (step 2) had me stumped until I looked more closely and realized that it's actually implemented (somewhat obscurely) in the `Tree` API: a special value for the `order` argument of `treepositions()`. The `x` you are after is just the index of `target_leafpos` in this list.

```
>>> target_leafpos = np.treeposition() + np.leaf_treeposition(0) # Step 1
>>> all_leaf_treepositions = t.treepositions("leaves")           # Step 2
>>> x = all_leaf_treepositions.index(target_leafpos)
>>> print(x)
3
```

If you don't mind unreadable code, you could even write it as an one-liner:

```
x = t.treepositions("leaves").index( np.treeposition()+np.leaf_treeposition(0) )
```

Comment: That works, many thanks ! (treepositions("leaves"), good catch !)